# How to get specific post meta by title or id

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, post-meta

I have register bellow custom post type in function.php and I am using `Advanced Custom Fields`. Using advance custom field type I have added one `image` field and assigned to my `Release` custom post type.

Now I have added one post inside Release post type. I have fill this details in this post.

**Title:** Speak Now (Deluxe Edition)
**Image:** Added some Image

Now I want to retrieve meta data with specific post by title/id.

I have tried this code but not working:

```
$my_post_meta = get_post_meta(556, 'album_image', true);
    if ( ! empty ( $my_post_meta ) ) {
        get_field('album_image');
    }
```

**My custom post type:**

```
/**
 * Music/Releases
 *
 */
function codex_custom_init5() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Releases',
    'singular_name'      => 'Release',
    'add_new'            => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Release',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Release',
    'new_item'           => 'New Release',
    'all_items'          => 'All Releases',
    'view_item'          => 'View Release',
    'search_items'       => 'Search Releases',
    'not_found'          => 'No release found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No release found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Release'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'release' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'release', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init5' );
```

[image: My Post Type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_field` is a replacement for `get_post_meta` you have to use only it:

```
$my_post_meta = get_field('album_image', 556);

if ( ! empty($my_post_meta) ) {
   // use the image
}
```

If you don't know the ID and want retrieve the post meta via post name, you have to use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` to ge the post via slug:

```
$posts = get_posts('post_name=here-the-post-name&post_type=release');
$mypost = ( ! empty($posts) ) ? array_pop($posts) : false;
$my_post_meta = $mypost ? get_field('album_image', $mypost->ID) : '';
if ( ! empty($my_post_meta) ) {
  // use the image
}
```

Comment: get_posts() now accepts array of args. Also, the slug is represents by the argument: "name" and not "post_name". https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/